# GCP CloudRun - Add NAT Gateway or Internal Service Ingress All?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc, google-nat-gateway

In `CloudRun`:

`public-service` needs to talk to `internal-service` and the `internet`

`internal-service` talks to the `internet`

Option1: Ideally, `internal-service` has ingress as `internal`, but in doing so, `public-service` requires a `vpc-connector` for `all-traffic`, which means it also needs a `NAT` gateway added.

Option-2: Alternatively, `internal-service` can have ingress as `all` and `--no-allow-unauthenticated`.

Option-1 looks a bit complex. What is recommended? What are the security risks to Option-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VPC contain a default route that forward the traffic to the internet if no IP match in your VPC

[image]

Therefore, you don't need a Cloud NAT. Cloud NAT is useful if you want to go to the internet with a static and your own IP, not with a shared and random IP.

Option 1 is the best, without cloud nat overhead.

---

**EDIT 1**

I was sure that the default internet route wasn't delete-able. Thanks to your comment, I checked and.... no, you can delete it. Only the priority 0 rules aren't removable.

But that also means you can recreate it, like that

```
gcloud beta compute routes create default-to-internet \
 --network=default --priority=1000 --destination-range=0.0.0.0/0 \
 --next-hop-gateway=default-internet-gateway
```

Stay on the option 1 ;)

Comment: My GCP consultant and I have been trying to get this to work, it must be something with my setup but the default mode to the internet doesn't appear to be working, calls to the outside internet from `public-service` can't get out. I will have to go with option 2 for sake of time. If you think you might know what settings I should look into I'm all ears!

Comment: I edited my answer. I was convinced of the opposite! Thanks for that, I sharped more my GCP skill!

Comment: @KevinDanikowski, did you have activated this organisation policy `Skip default network creation` in your project, folder or organization? It could be a side effect of it.

Comment: thanks for your update. So my GCP consultant was puzzled by this problem, since we still couldn't connect to the outside internet or find documentation on this method. He created a brand new project, VPC connector, ect. and eventually determined I needed to have a NAT after all. We didn't have a skip default network creation on this nor his blank new project. Have you been able to connect without a NAT before?

Comment: Yes, it always worked like that. That's why, it's so simple for me and I recommend this solution. I will try to create a bunch of new project tomorrow and to see if some options can raise the same issue.

Comment: did you create some test projects? I got it to work with the NAT gateway, but I have one CloudRun service that just refuses to access the NAT gateway for some reason. I'm debating to delete it and re-create it. Seems like some CloudRun bug that I've encountered similarly in other situations.

Comment: Yes I tested on a bunch of project with different option in organization policies and so on. I was unable to reproduce your case where the default internet gateway wasn't present. The support could be able to help you more than me=!